# kubernetes pod names Keep changing

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I need to make some automation testing on the Kubernetes pod but the pods names keeps changing
like at first it was **hisham-7cc8f99597** then after some time it is like this
**hisham-7cc8f99597-8j8lj**
is there a way I can know what is the name of the pod right now so I can use the name in the automation scenario ?

Comment: Why do you need to know the specific pod name?  If you're trying to make requests to it, usually you'd do it through a Service, which will have a fixed name.

Answer (score 2):

Pods are [cattle, not pets (`devops.stackexchange.com`)](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/653/what-is-the-definition-of-cattle-not-pets). Thus, pods do not have an identity. We should therefore never directly communicate with a pod, but rather expose pods through a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) and communicate with the service instead. The service has a well-defined and constant name.

Answer (score 1):

The variation in the name is due to you using Deployments, and is by design.

If you really need to use automation, don't go by pod name, go via the deployment. So instead of using

```
kubectl exec -it -n {namespace} {podname} -- {command}
```

Use

```
kubectl exec -it -n {namespace} deployments/{name-of-deployment} -- {command}
```

This will randomly pick one of the deployment pods to run the command. Since all the pods are replicas, each one should behave the same way, so the results should be the same.

You can also do some stdout manipulation such as :

```
kubectl get pods -n {namespace} \
  -l {label1}={value1} --no-headers | \
  awk '{print $1)' | head
```

To pick the first pod in the listing

You can also use a statefulset instead of a deployment which will name your pods in a known manner: `{statefulset}-0`, `{statefulset}-1` and so on and you can then go to a specific one for your command.

Answer (score 0):

To get the predictable pod names you must use state full sets

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your tests do and why do you need to know the Pod's name.

**If you just need the Pod's name:**

Assuming you have access to the cluster and kubectl in your tests, and that your pod is part of a deployment that has a specific label like `app=nginx`, you can query for its name like this:

`kubectl get po --selector=app=nginx-o=name`

The output will be something like

`pod/yourDeploymentName-7bd6c579fd-7gxzn`

You can trim the leading `pod/` through awk:

`kubectl get po --selector=app=nginx-o=name | awk -F "/" '{print $2}'`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the pod name dynamically

```
MYPOD=$(kubectl get pods \
    -n your_namesoace \
    --selector='your_app_selector' \
    -o \
    jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name)
```

This query will give you the first pod, after filtering it by namespace and release / app selector name.

You can run in a for loop and execute a dynamic script.

Answer (score 0):

To maintain the same name for pods after deployment in Kubernetes, you can use a combination of labels and selectors.

When you create a deployment, you can define a set of labels for the pods that will be created by the deployment. For example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-container
        image: my-image:latest
```

In this example, the app: my-app label is assigned to the pod template. This label is then used in the selector to ensure that the pods created by the deployment have the same label. This means that if a pod is deleted or replaced, the deployment will automatically create a new pod with the same label and name.

To verify that the pods have the same name as the deployment, you can use the following command:

```
kubectl get pods -l app=my-app
```

This will list all the pods with the app=my-app label, including the ones created by the deployment.

Answer (score -2):

Here just answering your answering as you have asked, otherwise it's good to use the **service name** for communication not POD name if you are using that.

Either you can run your workload as `POD` however it's not good idea if you are running it as `deployment`.

If you are running as **POD** you can maintain the single name each time you want.

**Extra** :

You can also use the metadata or downwardAPI to get the details of the existing POD.

**name** will get injected into the environment variable (MY_POD_NAME) and your automation can get it automatically, use it with `os.env`.

**Example :**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dapi-envars-fieldref
spec:
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
      command: [ "sh", "-c"]
      args:
      - while true; do
          echo -en '\n';
          printenv MY_NODE_NAME MY_POD_NAME MY_POD_NAMESPACE;
          printenv MY_POD_IP MY_POD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT;
          sleep 10;
        done;
      env:
        - name: MY_NODE_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.nodeName
        - name: MY_POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: MY_POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: MY_POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        - name: MY_POD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: spec.serviceAccountName
```

Read more at : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/